# Why is this site not showing up in "More stack exchange communities"?

Tags: bug, support

When I click on the little Stack Exchange icon in the upper-right corner of the viewport, it shows a list of "Your communities" and "More Stack Exchange communities".

Why does this site not appear in the list of "More Stack Exchange communities"?

Comment: It's probably because this site is in private beta. But I'm not really sure I understand how it works.

Answer (score 6):

[Trebor](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/trebor) is right - [private betas do not appear in that list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253374/have-private-betas-in-your-communities-list-in-the-stack-exchange-dropdown#comment827619_253374).

You can, however, add it to Your Communities already:

[image]